# How to find/compare a specific line inside a text File? Using C#

Tags: c#

I have a program for a little enterprise, that in a `Form` you may add new users, this new user-names will be added in a text file named: `employees.txt` like this:

`User 1`

`User 2`

`User 3`

`User 4`

(Without space between the users)

In a second `Form`, when you want to close the Application, you need write in a `textBox` which user want close the app and then compare the `textbox` `string` with the names inside `employees.txt` and if they match, the application will close.
How to compare a specific line inside a text File?

Or how I can do that?

Comment: a little enterprise :-)

Comment: Why are you using a text file and not a simple database that can be shared?  There are plenty of free ones available that will make things a LOT simpler.

Comment: @DStanley I kinda new programming in C#, I don't know how use database and that stuff, so I do this program like that because I thought this way will be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] users = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("employees.txt");
if(users.Any(u=> u == username)) Application.Exit(); // changed assignment to equality comparison
```

Comment: Please also consider the possibility to use string.Compare and specify StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase to ignore case, and also using trim function to drop whitespace

Comment: @ironstone13 I am newbie in c# programming, how can I use trim function?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx
Check if the string is null before calling this method, to avoid getting NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

start out by reading the file into an array like this using File.ReadAllLines

see - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Then use various linq methods (like Any, Where, etc) to search the array